# How can I return the first truthy value in Elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, pattern-matching

I'm working through the textbook *Learn functional programming with Elixir* and I am unsatisfied with some of the given answers to the example problems.  The problem as stated centres around checking the winner of a game of tic-tac-toe, but I'll try to boil it down to its essence.  Suppose we want to check the validity of some tuple of values and return something back, for example

```
iex(1)> some_function({:some, :list, :of, :values})
{:ok}
iex(2)> some_function({:some, :other, :list, :of, :values})
{:error}
```

the textbook solution was to match on exactly the allowed values:

```
def some_function({_, _, :of, _}), do: {:ok}
def some_function(_everything_else), do: {:error}
```

however, I didn't like this solution because with a large number of cases it becomes very repetitive.  I attempted to encode the logic more directly, but I couldn't figure out an idiomatic way to do it.  I tried:

```
def some_function(input) do
  test1(input) or
  test2(input) or
  {:error}
end

def test1({:some, :case}), do: false
def test1({:some, :other, :case}), do: {:ok}  

def test2({:some, :case}), do: false
def test2({:some, :other, :case}), do: {:ok}
```

this works when all of the tests fail, but when any of them pass you get an error that you can't compare {:ok} as a boolean.  What I ended up doing, though I realize it's hideous, is

```
def some_function(input) do
  cond do
    test1(input) -> test1(input)
    test2(input) -> test2(input)
    fail(input) -> {:error}
  end
end

def test1({:some, :case}), do: false
def test1({:some, :other, :case}), do: {:ok}  

def test2({:some, :case}), do: false
def test2({:some, :other, :case}), do: {:ok}

def fail(_input), do: true
```

This actually behaves perfectly from a black box perspective, however the code is laced with repetition (especially each test must be evaluated twice in order to ascertain truthiness and capture the value).  Is there an idiomatic way return the first truthy value given a series of test cases to be evaluated?  I'm well-versed in python and C but I'm trying to avoid the use of `if` and do this in a "functional" style.

Comment: "I didn't like this solution because with a large number of cases it becomes very repetitive" -> nothing wrong with repetition if it's clear, simple, and to the point. I think a list of function clauses representing valid winning states, for example, is very clear.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip I suppose that is a fair counterpoint. my inner programmer voice says that it's too inelegant but given that functional code is (at least for me) more difficult to reason about than imperative code maybe I _should_ be erring more on the side of "explicit and clear" instead of "elegant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [`or/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#or/2), unlike [`||/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%7C/2), expects *boolean* arguments, while the latter would accept any value, treating `nil` and `false` as `falsey` and everything else as `truthy` value.
2. Single element tuple makes a little sense in a vast majority of cases, use an atom itself (`{:ok}` → `:ok`.)
3. There is [`Enum.find/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#find/3) that expects an enumerable which tuple is not, but we have [`Tuple.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#to_list/1) and one might convert an input to list and call `Enum.find/3`.
4. As Adam said in comments, the pattern matching solution is concise and workes pretty well in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your help! it was 100% `||/2` that did what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern matching is idiomatic, however, as you noted, it can be bulky when applied against a large number of cases and it may not work if you don't know the things you need to match until runtime.  The given solution required that the tuple had a specific member *at a specific index*, whereas it seems like you are going more for an open-ended solution.

As a variant to what others have suggested, you could try something that uses `Enum.member?/2`, e.g. something that tests whether or not the tuple contains the thing you're looking for:

```
iex> {:some, :list, :of, :values}
|> Tuple.to_list()
|> Enum.member?(:of)
true
```

Or, if you want to check whether or not the tuple contains any of a *list* of acceptable values, you could make use of `Enum.any?/2`, e.g. by defining the list of acceptable values in a guard clause

```
iex> {:some, :list, :of, :values}
|> Tuple.to_list()
|> Enum.any?(fn
  x when x in [:of] -> true
  _ -> false
end)

true
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69632573/2035262 :)

Comment: Ah thanks for the help but the problem as posed was about finding a winner in tic-tac-toe, I tried to "simplify" but giving an example problem about finding elements in a list to make it easier but maybe I just made it more confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, here is a performant solution with a bit of metaprogramming that generates all the clauses for all the tuples possible (max tuple size is given as an argument)

```elixir
defmodule Checker do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    total = Keyword.get(opts, :count, 8)

    for count <- 1..total, place <- 1..count do
      pre = for _ <- 1..place - 1//1, do: Macro.var(:_, nil)
      post = for _ <- place + 1..count//1, do: Macro.var(:_, nil)

      quote do
        def member?(what,
          {unquote_splicing(pre), what, unquote_splicing(post)}
        ), do: true
      end
    end ++ [quote do: (def member?(_, _), do: false)]
  end
end

defmodule Test do
  use Checker, count: 4
end
```

Test it as:

```elixir
Test.member? :ok, {:ok}
#⇒ true
Test.member? :ok, {42, true, :ok, :foo}
#⇒ true
Test.member? :ok, {42, true, :foo}
#⇒ false
```